# Is there a function to strip empty values at the end of a delimited column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataset looks like below :

**Dataset:**

```
a1~ ~s  ~   ~abcb1~ ~5~ ~abcdef~    ~1700000~   ~abc~   ~0~ ~0~ ~0.48~  ~0~ ~~  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
a2~ ~s  ~   ~defb1  ~   ~ghijk~ ~37000000~  ~def~   ~0~ ~0~ ~0.00~  ~0~ ~0~ ~99~
a3~ ~s  ~   ~cawb1~ ~5~ ~lmnop~ ~1700000~   ~caw~   ~0~ ~ ~0~   ~0.00~  ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~
a3~ ~s  ~   ~cawb1~ ~5~ ~lmnop~ ~1700000~   ~caw~   ~0~ ~ ~0~   ~0.00~  ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~
```

I am trying to read the dataset , remove the  duplicates and  write  to csv by following code :

**Code Snippet:**

```
interim = pd.read_csv(currentFilePath, delimiter="~", header=None , engine='python',dtype=str, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, doublequote = False)
 interim.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
 interim.to_csv(currentFilePath, sep="~", index=False, header=False, doublequote = False)
```

**Issue:**
I expect the  output to be the same except the  duplicates to be removed  as  below .But I see  delimiter being added at the end of  the row  a2 as  below .Could you please  suggest if there is  way to fix this ?

**Expected output:**

```
a1~ ~s  ~   ~abcb1~ ~5~ ~abcdef~    ~1700000~   ~abc~   ~0~ ~0~ ~0.48~  ~0~ ~~  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
a2~ ~s  ~   ~defb1  ~   ~ghijk~ ~37000000~  ~def~   ~0~ ~0~ ~0.00~  ~0~ ~0~ ~99~
a3~ ~s  ~   ~cawb1~ ~5~ ~lmnop~ ~1700000~   ~caw~   ~0~ ~ ~0~   ~0.00~  ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~
```

**Actual output:**.

```
a1~ ~s  ~   ~abcb1~ ~5~ ~abcdef~    ~1700000~   ~abc~   ~0~ ~0~ ~0.48~  ~0~ ~~  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
a2~ ~s  ~   ~defb1  ~   ~ghijk~ ~37000000~  ~def~   ~0~ ~0~ ~0.00~  ~0~ ~0~ ~99~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a3~ ~s  ~   ~cawb1~ ~5~ ~lmnop~ ~1700000~   ~caw~   ~0~ ~ ~0~   ~0.00~  ~0~ ~0~ ~0~ ~
0~  ~0~ ~0~ ~
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be not to use pandas, but to remove the duplicate rows from the csv file directly. Easiest way is to do this from the command line. For linux:

```
sort -u input_file.csv -o output_file.csv
```

Otherwise you could use `python`:

```
s = set()
with open('output_filename.csv', 'w') as out:
    for line in open('input_filename.csv'):
        if line not in s:
            out.write(line)
            s.add(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

remember that `NA!= NA`,
try something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter="~", header=None )
df = df.fillna(0).drop_duplicates()
```